# Data in ajax json not defined

Tags: c#, json, ajax

this is my data looks like in json in harcoded way. But i want to retreive the data from database. so it can be display in html like how json display it.

```
menu_data =  {
    "name": "Abu",
    "menus": [
        {
            "menu_id": 1,
            "name": "Food",
            "icon": "fa-hdd-o",
            "col": 4,
            "site": Ind,
            "subs": [
                [
                    {
                        "name": "Cake",
                        "path": "",
                        "url": "",
                        "tabs": "",
                        "param": ""
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "Cheese Cake",
                        "path": "",
                        "url": "",
                        "tabs": "",
                        "param": ""
                    },                        
                    {
                        "name": "Choc Cake",
                        "path": "",
                        "url": "",
                        "tabs": "",
                        "param": ""
                    },

                ],
            ]
        },
    ],
    "gid": "00001",
    "message": null
};
```

But i want to get all this data from database which means i need to get the data from web service.
This is my code in webservice c#.

```
    public class wsResult
    {
        public string message;
    }
    public class wsMenu
    {
        public string menu_id;
        public string name;
        public string icon;
        public string site;
        public string col;
        public List<string> subs = new List<string>();
    }
    public class wsHome : wsResult
    {
        public string name;
        public List<wsMenu> menus;
        public string gid;
    }
    [WebMethod]
    [ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json, UseHttpGet = false)]
    public List<wsMenu> GetModName()
    {
        List<wsMenu> food = new List<wsMenu>();
        {
            using (DbConnection conn = SingLibrary.CreateConnection("foodddb_dev"))
            {
                conn.Open();
                DbCommand cmd = SingLibrary.CreateCommand(conn);
                cmd.CommandText = String.Format(
                                                @"select name, menu_id, site from 
                food_menu ");
                DbDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                while (dr.Read())
                {
                    wsMenu op = new wsMenu();
                    op.name = dr["name"].ToString();
                    op.menu_id = dr["menu_id"].ToString();
                    op.site = dr["site"].ToString();
                    food.Add(op);
                }
                dr.Close();

            }
        }
        return food ;
    }
```

and this is my ajax script...

```
function setMenu() {

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    url: "ws.asmx/GetModName",
    data: menu_data,
    dataType: "json",
    async: true,
    success: function (menu_data) {
        menu_data = menu_data.d;
        console.log("this is menu data length " + menu_data.length);
    },
    error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        console.log(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown);
    }
});
```

I getting this error " menu_data is null " and "menu data is not defined"

Answer (score 0):

try to remove data: and content type from ajax

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",

    url: "ws.asmx/GetModName",
   
    dataType: "json",
   
    success: function (menu_data) {
        menu_data = menu_data.d;
        console.log("this is menu data length " + menu_data.length);
    },
    error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        console.log(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown);
    }
});
```